# Copy filtered data to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy filtered data to another workbook and it is giving me Run-Time error '1004'.

```
Sub DS()
'
' DS Macro
'
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("H:\L\Roy\H AND E\2020\SAP - ZPSD02_template2\")
'
    'Selection.AutoFilter
    Worksheets("ST TO ST").Range("$A$1:$O$1").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="PENDING"
    lastRow = Worksheets("ST TO ST").Range("J" & Worksheets("ST TO ST").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
    Worksheets("ST TO ST").Range("$A$1:$O$1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="U3R", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="U2R"
    Worksheets("ST TO ST").Range("J2:J" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                 Destination:=wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Worksheets("ST TO ST").Range("C2:C" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                 Destination:=wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
    Worksheets("ST TO ST").Range("D2:D" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                 Destination:=wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1")
    Worksheets("ST TO ST").Range("H2:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                 Destination:=wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1")
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error and what is the full message?

Comment: Your file path for `wb` looks invalid to me

Comment: Your `Workbooks.Open` line has a full path, but there is no filename at the end. How do you expect it to know which file to open?

Comment: @braX The end name is the file name.

Comment: if `SAP - ZPSD02_template2` is a filename, then remove the backslash at the end, and give it the right extension. (.xls, .xlsx, .xlsm, etc)

Comment: @BigBen "Set wb ....." is the line which gives the error   The error is "Run-time erroe'1004'      Excel cannot access the file....there are several possible reasons....file name or path does not exist.....file is being used by another program.....workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a...

Comment: @braX I don't get the error now..but its giving me Run-time error '9' for the next line..."Worksheets ("S to S".......

Comment: Now you need to qualify `Worksheets("ST TO ST")` with your `wb` object like this: `wb.Worksheets("ST TO ST")`

Comment: @Roy In my answer just replace the path with the right one and adjust the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that your workbook path points to a folder, you need to point it to a file.

EDIT: **As stated in your comment**

`targetWorkbookPath = "H:\L\Roy\H AND E\2020\SAP - ZPSD02_template2.xlsx"` (or xlsm)

Check the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

**EDIT 2:** Took the paths you added in the Edit and incorporated them in the code.

**Code:**

```
Sub DS()

    Dim sourceWorkook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Dim sourceWorkbookPath As String
    Dim targetWorkbookPath As String
    Dim lastRow As Long


    ' Define workbooks paths
    sourceWorkbookPath = "H:\L\Roy\RT\Transfers\Transfers 2020 - Roy.xlsm"
    targetWorkbookPath = "H:\L\Roy\H and E\2020\SAP - ZPSD02_template2.xlsx"

    ' Set a reference to the target Workbook and sheets
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourceWorkbookPath)
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookPath)

    ' definr worksheet's names for each workbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("ST TO ST")
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With sourceSheet

        ' Get last row
        lastRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="PENDING"
        .Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="U3R", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="U2R"

        .Range("J2:J" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A1")
        .Range("C2:C" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("B1")
        .Range("D2:D" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("E1")
        .Range("H2:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("F1")
    End With
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi @RicardoDiaz it is giving me runtime error '9' in the line after "Selection Autofilter"

Comment: If you don't have already set the filter, is going to give you trouble. Let me adjust it.

Comment: Ok. see edit 2. You have to make sure that the sheet's names are correct

Comment: Hi @RicardoDiaz It is giving me Run time erroe '9'  in the setsourcesheet line....also set sourceworkbook was missing a 'b'

Comment: I have updated the code .Sorry about the typo. I don't have those workbooks so I couldn't test it.

Comment: Hi @RicardoDiaz Thank you!  I still can't figure out why is it giving runtime error '9' in the sourcesheet line

Comment: Hi @RicardoDiaz I tried again and it worked. Thanks for your help! Appreciate that!